# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderation

This has been mentioned in chat, and is one of the [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

You are encouraged to nominate yourself or someone else for the position of [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).  One nomination per answer.

Comment: I've never participated in any SE moderator election, how it's done? Should I vote on the answers below, or there is a separated procedure?

Comment: @Sekhemty: I think you vote on the answers below for the `Moderator Pro Tempore` and eventually a full-blown election occurs (after public Beta I believe).

Comment: @Sekhemty - As far as I know, Stack Exchange community team chooses, but presumably they take into account the nominations and the votes in this Q&A. In the olden days, they merely chose on their own, with no Meta thread IIRC. Once the site leaves the public Beta, they hold real elections.

Comment: @Sekhemty - I am reasonably sure that DVK's explanation is correct.

Comment: As DVK notes, the first round of moderators are not elected at all but appointed by the community team at StackExchange. This meta post is just one thing they will read and factor in when they internally review who to nominate. Voting here gives them some idea how the community feels about members, but they also take other things into consideration. Later if the site makes it through beta and graduates one of the first orders of business is to hold full blown elections.

Comment: Be aware it can be a big commitment. On travel.SE, the initial pro-tempore moderators ended up doing it for just short of 2 years before the first official election was held.

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to nominate [Jason Down](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/142/jason-down):

- In the short time since E-books launched, [he has gained 988 reputation](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/142/jason-down?tab=reputation)<sup>*</sup>.
- He is [an active member](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/142/jason-down?tab=activity) of E-books.
- He is also [an active member](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9732/jason-down) of Stack Overflow.

**Nominee response:** I accept the nomination.

<sub>* I realize that reputation isn't everything, but it does show that many users found his answers useful.</sub>

Comment: How's his "moderation" activity?

Comment: I'd be willing to put in the necessary time :) Thanks for the nod @NathanOsman.

Comment: @JasonDown - you can start by putting in the same moderation link you put into my nomination :) [ I stole the idea for the format for nominations for mature SE site moderator elections ]

Answer (score 9):

I would like to nominate [Nathan Osman](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/45/nathan-osman):

- Has been instrumental in setting up E-books.
- Has moderator experience on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com)
- Has a cumulative reputation of 70K+ on the various Stackoverflow/Stackexchange sites.

---

**Nominee response (Unable to edit himself at this time)**: [I accept the nomination](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94/who-should-the-moderators-be/111#comment215_111).

Comment: +1 - Previous moderator experience is a big plus.

Comment: The circle is complete. Now we watch how SE team handles directed graphs with loops :)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't actually edit this answer. I don't yet have enough reputation. (This is embarrassing.) Anyway, I do accept the nomination. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I would nominate [Anthon](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/60/anthon). He seems to both be:

- [Active in user level moderation via editing](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/60/anthon?tab=activity&sort=revisions)
- [Active in user level moderation via reviewing](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/60/anthon?tab=activity&sort=reviews)
- Very knowledgeable about subject matter
- [Reasonably active on meta](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60/anthon)

<sub>I accept the nomination, as indicated on the [Moderator Pro Tempore moderator](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) page, by editing this answer.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

I would like to nominate [DVK](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/139/dvk):

- Acquired quite a bit of [reputation](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/139/dvk?tab=reputation) since E-books has launched by providing both high quality [answers](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/139/dvk?tab=answers) and [questions](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/139/dvk?tab=questions) (we need more to keep the site alive people!).
- Proven to be active with high reputation on many [other stack exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/users/41067/dvk?tab=accounts).
- Already performs [many moderation tasks](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/139/dvk?tab=activity&sort=revisions).

---

**Nominee response**: I accept the nomination.

Comment: Thanks for the nod :)

Comment: @DVK: No problem. I think the site would benefit with you as a moderator.